# How do I utilize the error and success facets in a p:ajaxStatus

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm attempting to provide feedback about ajax request to my users on a JSF page. I defined a primefaces poll component that periodically sends requests to the server and. This is working fine so far. I want to let the users know about the current state with the help of a primefaces ajaxStatus component. I defined it as follows:

```
<p:ajaxStatus>
  <f:facet name="default"><h:outputText value="default"/></f:facet>
  <f:facet name="start"><h:outputText value="start"/></f:facet>
  <f:facet name="success"><h:outputText value="success"/></f:facet>
  <f:facet name="error"><h:outputText value="error"/></f:facet>
  <f:facet name="complete"><h:outputText value="complete"/></f:facet>
</p:ajaxStatus>
```

The problem I'm facing is that the success and error facets are never visible or more precisely never visible for a time long enough to actually perceive them.

Now I verified that the facets I defined are translated to divs with correctly generated ids consisting of a prefix plus the corresponding facet's name. I debugged the corresponding primefaces javascript and found it simply applies 'display: none;' as inline style to all facets and then removes the style again from the facet that represents the current state whenever an ajax event occurs.

Now the part that I don't understand is how to utilize the error and success facets then. The complete event always immediately follows the success and error events. Via debugging I verified the success and error events are actually triggered and their facets are also being made visible. But the time between the success / error events and the subsequent complete event is so little you cannot perceive the appearance of the success and error events at all not even as a screen flickering.

Now my questions are:

1. Is there anything I have conceptually not understood about how to use the error and success facets?
2. Is there any way to prevent the complete facet to immediately replace the error and success facets? Omitting the complete facet does not have any effect. No facet at all is then shown on completion of the ajax requests.
3. What is the point of having the success and error facets when they actually never get visible?

**EDIT:** In the meantime the issue was resolved. It was a bug in primefaces and will be fixed in version 6.3. Here is the corresponding bugreport I created: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3625.
I also provided a pull request that resolved the issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/3653. For anyone interested in a workaround, you can build primefaces yourself and apply the following change to it: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/commit/33fa3e55239b5bd974fa88b0f5ce29d02a5c3557. This will fix the issue.

Thanks to @kukeltje for encouraging me to post the issue on the primefaces bugtracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No.
2. The source of the component is in https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/ajaxstatus/ajaxstatus.js. You could override the `bind` or `trigger` functions in there to delay hiding the error facet when it happens. You could even make it so it needs to be actively closed.. But... (see below)
3. There is none.

... I've never used the declarative way for errors. I always just used the start... So never noticed this behaviour. But then again, the error is **only** for errors in the technical handling of the javascript request. Not for handling error from the server as a result of the javascript ajax call. Think e.g. when the internet connection is gone, you cannot make an ajax call. Those kinds of errors.

A workaround would be to use the

```
<p:ajaxStatus onstart="alert('Start')" oncomplete="alert('End') onerror="alert('Error')"/>
```

In them you have access to `this` which contains the information about the error if I am right.

But it might be worth to at least post an issue in the issue list about the rather useslessness of the success and error facets.

Comment: The issue is currently in the process of being resolved, see [here](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/3625). As soon as this is done I'll update the question and the answer. Thanks for encouraging me to post an issue.

Comment: You even provided a Pull Request I noticed... Great! The PF source is rather good to understand/comprehend in my not so humble opinion